# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body around: Value "channel" is not snowflake

Tags: javascript

I have this code:

```js
let channel = this.textChannel.id;
this.textChannel.messages.fetch({around: "channel", limit: 1})
    .then(messages => {
        messages.first().edit(nowplaying);
    });
```

But when I run it, I get the error

```
UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: DiscordAPIError: Invalid Form Body around:
Value “channel” is not snowflake
```

Hope someone can help me.

Comment: According to the [docs](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/ChannelLogsQueryOptions) the `around` property needs to be a message id (a snowflake) so the string `"channel"` is not valid there

Comment: use catch() so that it won't error out